# getting warning Invalid argument for foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

In foreach loop i am getting warning Invalid argument supplied for foreach() below is my loop code and modal code please let me know where i done wrong

**Controller**

```
$concond = array("con_id"=>1,"con_status"=>1);
$this->data['contact']=$this->Frontend_model->get_contact($concond);
$this->load->view('frontend/clienthome',$this->data);
```

**foreach Loop**

```
if($contact)
{  
  foreach($contact as $foot)
  { 
     $footadr1 = $foot->con_addr_line_1;
     $footadr2 = $foot->con_addr_line_2;
     $footcity = $foot->con_city;
     $footstate = $foot->con_state;
     $footcountry = $foot->con_country;
     $footpin = $foot->con_pincode;
     $footp1 = $foot->con_phone_1;
     $footp2 = $foot->con_phone_2;
     $footp3 = $foot->con_phone_3;
     $footp4 = $foot->con_phone_4;
     $footemail = $foot->con_email_id;
  }
}
```

**modal**

```
function get_contact($concond)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('is_addres_contact');
  $this->db->where($concond);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your controller as well.

Comment: posted the code of controller @MatthijsOtterloo

Comment: Yes, posted a fix!

Comment: @PavanGS you print_r($contact) in view  check you got result in view.

Comment: you declare $this->data=array(); add in controller. then you can used  $this->data['contact']

Comment: i don't see anything wrong in your code - make a var_dump of $contact in your view after the if and post the result

Comment: Try to display first the value of your $contact variable to see if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I got your problem! 
You should try to do it like this:

```
$data['contact'] = $this->Frontend_model->get_contact($concond);
$this->load->view('frontend/clienthome', $data);
```

Comment: $this->data['contact']=$this->Frontend_model->get_contact($concond);
$this->load->view('frontend/clienthome',$this->data);   this also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try in model

```
function get_contact($con_id, $con_stat)
{
  $this->db->where('con_id', $con_id);
  $this->db->where('con_status', $con_stat);
  $query = $this->db->get('is_addres_contact');
  return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
$con_id = '1';
$con_stat = '1';

$this->data['contact'] = $this->frontend_model->get_contact($con_id, $con_stat);

$this->load->view('frontend/clienthome',$this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this,

**In model,**

```
function get_contact($concond)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('is_addres_contact');
  $this->db->where($concond);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

**In View**

```
if($contact)
{  
  foreach($contact as $foot)
  { 
     $footadr1 = $foot['con_addr_line_1'];
     $footadr2 = $foot['con_addr_line_2'];
     $footcity =$foot['con_city'];
     $footstate = $foot['con_state'];
     $footcountry = $foot['con_country'];
     $footpin = $foot['con_pincode'];
     $footp1 = $foot['con_phone_1'];
     $footp2 = $foot['con_phone_2'];
     $footp3 = $foot['con_phone_3'];
     $footp4 = $foot['con_phone_4'];
     $footemail = $foot['con_email_id'];
  }
}
```

Comment: like wolfgang1983 answer - this can't be the solution - this is just another way to do this...